# Change (color of) image along with link on hover/click

Tags: html, css

so I've been working with Javascript (Vue) and html since *yesterday* (so please forgive my noob-ness), and I can't figure out how to change the color of my image that's next to the "Home" Link description at the same time as the link.

I've tried using CSS classes, which work but only change the image color when you actually hover over the image and not the whole link line. Aside from CSS, I've also tried just changing the image to the colorized version through "onmouseover", but somehow that changed the icon to the colorized version immediately (?). I'm guessing the problem is that I control the link color through a:hover and the image color through a separate class, so the image color doesn't get connected to the link, but I don't know how to fix this?

You can find the document icon in white [here](https://i.imgur.com/VWOy5HI.png) and in red [here](https://i.imgur.com/nuZwxOS.png).

Thank you so much in advance!

---

Below just a snippet for the "Home" part of the sidebar:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="currentUser" class="vertical-nav bg-dark" id="sidebar">
      <div class="py-1 px-3 mb-4 bg-dark">
      </div>
      <ul class="nav flex-column bg-dark mb-0">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white font-bold ">
            <div class="document"></div>
                    <i class="fa mr-3 text-primary fa-fw"></i>
                     Home
                </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and CSS:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color: white;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: white;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: rgb(202, 95, 95) !important;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: rgb(202, 95, 95) !important;

.document {
  width: 10px;
  height: 12px;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("assets/documentWhiteSmall.png") no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}

.document:hover {
  width: 10px;
  height: 12px;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("assets/otherDocRedSmall.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You can use `someparent:hover actualelement` for this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/dj7pxch0/

Comment: Since the div with class `.document` is inside the `<a>` hyperlink, something like : ` a:hover .document { url("assets/otherDocRedSmall.png"); }` should work, but I cannot get it to work in a stack snippet since I don't see the actual document icon. I guess it's due to font-awesome not being included here?

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your input! When I use this, somehow the image disappears completely in normal mode i.imgur.com/3y6usuC.png and then gets displayed somewhat above the link in hover mode i.imgur.com/e9ABesL.png :( even though it obviously works in Fiddle.

Comment: Can you put the code you currently have in the question? Ideally as [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can target your `.document` div depending on the hovering of `a` with css:

```
a .document {
  width: 10px;
  height: 12px;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("assets/documentWhiteSmall.png") no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover .document {
  width: 10px;
  height: 12px;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("assets/otherDocRedSmall.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! Somehow, I end up again without a symbol at all in normal mode and a dented version in hover mode, only here it also looks like it's not resizing the icon properly? https://i.imgur.com/VuACHNM.png

Comment: We need more of your code to examine what causes the result you see.
As a short guideline for the display, you can organize your nav-link with flex like `a.nav-link { display: flex; align-items: center; }`. You could use `::before` pseudo-class also for your symbols, so please show more of your code.